# How to find path o image so I can reload later again same image?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

How to get path on device of captured image ?
I am showing image and below I have switch when is off I show default image from project, when is on I want to show image which user captured.
In capture function I can set image to my imageView

```
#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    NSLog(@"%@", info);
    UIImage * imageTemp = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    if (imageTemp == nil)
        imageTemp = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self.image setImage:imageTemp];
}
```

and it sets image to imageview but I don't have path. I have print info and it looks like

```
{
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata =     {
        DPIHeight = 72;
        DPIWidth = 72;
        Orientation = 6;
        "{Exif}" =         {
            ApertureValue = "2.526068811667588";
            BrightnessValue = "5.667090406070278";
            ColorSpace = 1;
            DateTimeDigitized = "2013:05:14 01:02:48";
            DateTimeOriginal = "2013:05:14 01:02:48";
            ExposureMode = 0;
            ExposureProgram = 2;
            ExposureTime = "0.008620689655172414";
            FNumber = "2.4";
            Flash = 25;
            FocalLenIn35mmFilm = 35;
            FocalLength = "4.28";
            ISOSpeedRatings =             (
                50
            );
            MeteringMode = 5;
            PixelXDimension = 3264;
            PixelYDimension = 2448;
            SceneType = 1;
            SensingMethod = 2;
            ShutterSpeedValue = "6.862622389675391";
            SubjectArea =             (
                1631,
                1223,
                881,
                881
            );
            WhiteBalance = 0;
        };
        "{TIFF}" =         {
            DateTime = "2013:05:14 01:02:48";
            Make = Apple;
            Model = "iPhone 4S";
            Software = "6.1.3";
            XResolution = 72;
            YResolution = 72;
        };
    };
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.image";
    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "<UIImage: 0x20ac0470>";
}
```

but I cannot find anything what I can use to find path. How to find path o image so I can reload later again same image ?

Comment: There is no image path. All you have is the image in memory. There is no path unless you save it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this image later stages in your app then you will have to save the URL of the image.

If you want to extract the image URL and Image name you can do it in your current implemented delegate method it self. The `NSDictionary` info contains all the information about the image.

```
#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    NSURL *imagePath = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
    NSString *imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];
}
```

You can save image using `imagePath` at this stage inside `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't find path to captured image because iPhone don't save it to file if you capture image your from code.
In my opinion, you have 2 ways:

1) You can create a singleton class for remembering UIImage in variable, and than have access to it.

2) You can save captured image to file in cache folder and then get path to it;